# Mantis doesn't send email to se domain

Tags: php, email, mantis

Mantis (1.2.1, 1.2.4, and 1.2.5) sends emails to anyone under company.com domain, but fails for company.se domain (Sweden office).

Turning off email validation `$g_validate_email = OFF;` doesn't help. The domains aren't being limited as specified by `$g_limit_email_domain   = OFF;` in config_default_inc.php.

The mail server is specified correctly in php.ini (version 5.3.6) and can send emails to company.se when using Microsoft Outlook.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the log files of both mail servers (start with your local one). There should be some information in there which can help you troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: It depends on which mail server you are running and the configuration of that mail server. On my servers the mail logs are stored in /var/log

Comment: turned on php mail.log feature and it registers the mail as okay. The problem was with the webserver restricting emails outside the domain.